# How to Sum a Single Table from a join statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I am trying to execute a query but am having troubles with my sum part. I have table A and table B. I would like to sum  a column from table A where 2 columns from tables A and B are the same and fall in the same date and shift. However, the summing is including table B as well somehow.I am not sure why this is. How do I make it so that it only sums table A but still includes table B for the condition. Any help is most appreciated. Thank you.

```
SELECT Sum (a.TotalLbs)
FROM   TableA a
       INNER JOIN TableB b
               ON a.Wic = b.Wic
WHERE  a.DateTime = b.DateTime
       AND a.Shift = b.Shift
```

Comment: include some test data and expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there are multiple B rows matching an A row, the join generates multiple output rows.

You are not actually interested in any B values, you just want to know if there is any matching row:

```
SELECT Sum(TotalLbs)
FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableB b
              WHERE a.Wic      = b.Wic
                AND a.DateTime = b.DateTime
                AND a.Shift    = b.Shift)
```

Comment: I think you missed Wic column